# what is the reason behind the bad outputs gained by RNN, LSTM when using GloVe pretrained model in text classification?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embeddings, sentiment-analysis

the problem is with the results gained for accuracy and f1  afer training our model via pretrained models such as GloVe.
when I apply CNN as a classifier, the result are good as follows:

```
acc: 0.9345 - val_loss: 0.1513
```

but when I apply RNN and LSTM as a classifier the results will be as follows:

```
24931/24931 [==============================] - 188s 8ms/step - loss: 7.9559 - acc: 6.0166e-04 - val_loss: 7.9904 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/4
24931/24931 [==============================] - 189s 8ms/step - loss: 7.9645 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7.9904 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

the above result is reached both via RNN and LSTM.

the problem is that I use the same data set and the same structure and the same GloVe but I reach acc: 0.9345 for CNN and gain acc: 0.0000e+00 for both LSTM and RNN.
It is worth noting that I have changed optimizer but still get the same result. the applied dataset contains 41,399 items, totaling 60.3 MB and also is binary.
any guidance will be appreciated as I am a beginner in working with GloVe.

I apply keras with tensorflow backend with python 3.5 in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have already dealt with RNN and LSTM codes and finally I found tow solutons to achieve better result for accuracy measure which are as follows:
at first I change the activation function, optimizers and learning rate but it is worth noting that activation function has the most impact and the second trick which I have used is to removing stop words, now the code works fine.
I hope it is useful.